# On Space Change - Not After (For Mac Spaces)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I'm new to Mac development, so I can't tell if what I need to do is even possible.

I need to create an application that gets a callback for when a desktop space is about to change and when it successfully does.  I also need to override the change to cancel it if need be.  For example:

`Space Change Initiated -> Run My Code -> Change Space |OR| Cancel Space Change`

The only thing that I could find was: `NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification` which sends a callback when the space has successfully changed. This will not be good enough.

I'm not begging for code btw, just looking for a direction to be pointed in to achieve what I want (if at all possible).  I'm open to all suggestions, even if they are in different programming languages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is an exposed API for that.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yeah, I have a feeling you might be correct. I am wondering if it is possible to lock a workspace on command and verify identify before that space is accessible.

Comment: So, you're using it for access control?  Spaces is not designed for that.  Instead, after authentication, you can use fast user switching to change to a different logged-in user.  You could also try using kiosk mode, but I don't recommend it for access control.

Comment: I know it's not designed for that, it was something I thought I would experiment with. The lack of information on the net intrigued me more by proving it was either impossible or that no one had tried. I just thought I would put it out there and see if it was actually impossible.